# 2 Problems with SendKeys ^ escaped with "{^}" output & on DE key layout and ctrl was used in all escaped cases to the end of line

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I want to use SendKeys to enter a password.

1. When i use ^ in the string and it was wrapped with {} like SendKeys want it, the output of SendKeys is an & on DE (DE) key layout on EN (US) key layout it is ^ like given.
2. And with bothe key layouts i become a another unexpexted problem, afte using the escape of ^ with {^}, SendKeys think i want to press crtl in all escaped cases to the end of the line. I don´t find any documentation of this feature/bug.

```
string sProcess = "notepad";
string sTest = "!7(!X)um()-JDTd^/m+;s~ff()~+%^";

int PIDCount = Process.GetProcessesByName(sProcess).Count();

if (PIDCount == 1)
{
    Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName(sProcess).FirstOrDefault();
    
    if (p != null)
    {
        string sOldPW = Regex.Replace(sTest, "[+^%~()\\{\\}\\[\\]]", "{$0}");
        SendKeys.SendWait(sOldPW);
    }
}
```

Here are my source, replacment and results strings i became.

- Test String: !7(!X)um()-JDTd^/m+;s~ff()~+%^
- String after RegEx replacment for SendKeys: !7{(}!X{)}um{(}{)}-JDTd{^}/m{+};s{~}ff{(}{)}{~}{+}{%}{^}
- Test Output with DE (DE) key layout: !7(!X)um()-JDTd&7m+,s~ff89~+56
- Test Output with EN (US) key layout: !7(!X)um()-JDTd^/m+;s`ff90`+56

The Questions are:

1. How can i get on a DE (DE) key layout the ^ sing from SendKey?
2. How do i prevent Sendkey to not pressing the ctrl when i using the escape sequence of ^ for SendKey?

Comment: *SendKeys is an & on DE (DE) key layout on EN (US) key layout it is ^ like given* - yes, you'll note that on a US keyboard ^ is schieved by pressing SHIFT-6, and if you press SHIFT-6 on a de keyboard you get a & - oh the joys :/ Is "typing" the password out your only option?

Answer (score 1):

Since SendKeys probably does not represent the functionality needed for such a task, I have searched for an alternative to sendKeys and also found.
The nuget InputSimulator brings the necessary functionality.
https://csharp.hotexamples.com/de/examples/WindowsInput/InputSimulator/-/php-inputsimulator-class-examples.html

```
using WindowsInput;
using WindowsInput.Native;
```

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);
```

```
var sim = new InputSimulator();

string sProcess = "notepad";
string sTest = "!7(!X)um()-JDTd^/m+;s~ff()~+%^";

int PIDCount = Process.GetProcessesByName(sProcess).Count();

if (PIDCount == 1)
{
    if (p != null)
    {
        IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(h);
        Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName(sProcess).FirstOrDefault();
        sim.Keyboard.TextEntry(sTest);
    }
}
```